# What are the symbols for the following in Batch?

Tags: batch-file

```
if "%variable%" == "Some stuff" goto menu
if "%variable%" EQU "Some stuff" goto menu
```

They both serve the same function... `==` is the symbolic representation of `EQU`.

How do we show `NEQ`, `LES`, `LEQ`, `GTR`, `GEQ` in symbols?

Thank you.

Comment: we don't. We use, what [if](https://ss64.com/nt/if.html) offers: EQU, NEQ, LES, LEQ, GTR, GEQ. `==` is for compatibility reasons (replaced by `EQU`. It's the only one supported by DOS-`if`.

Comment: IF will only parse numbers when one of (EQU, NEQ, LSS, LEQ, GTR, GEQ) is used. 
The == comparison operator always results in a string comparison. https://ss64.com/nt/if.html

Comment: An addition to comment written by Stephan: `==` is the only comparison operator supported by MS-DOS, Windows 95 and Windows 98 (using command.com as command interpreter). For "not equal" it is possible to use `if not "%variable%" == "Some stuff" goto menu` even with those old operating systems which of course is also supported by Windows NT command interpreter cmd.exe. And the 3 letter based operators work only with command extensions enabled as by default. Use `setlocal DisableExtensions` at top of the batch file and Windows command interpreter is in "DOS/Win9x" mode with also no `/I`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

unluckily, only `EQU` has a equivalent symbol `==`, the `==` sign is used in string comparison though. and `IF` will only parse numbers when one of `(EQU, NEQ, LSS, LEQ, GTR, GEQ)` is used.

Here's an equivalent for `NEQ` though:

```
if NOT "%variable%" == "Some stuff" ::NEQ
```

Comment: "`if` will only parse numbers..."? No, can also handle strings with `xxx` comparators: `if Germany GTR Austria echo yes`. (I don't think, `if` knows how big both countries are...)

Comment: If one of the two arguments to compare can't be interpreted successfully with function [strtol](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtol/) for an integer comparison for example because of one argument starts with a double quote, Windows command interpreter runs automatically a string comparison with [strcmp](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/) which has as return value an integer with the values < 0, 0 and > 0 and therefore `EQU, NEQ, LSS, LEQ, GTR, GEQ` work all also on a string comparison. The comparison includes the surrounding double quotes.

Comment: One more note: `IF 020 EQU 20 (echo EQUAL) else (echo NOT EQUAL)` outputs `NOT EQUAL` because 020 is interpreted octal and has therefore the decimal value 16 which is not equal 20. See the Stack Overflow documentation page [Variables in Batch Files](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/batch-file/3528/) for details about string to integer conversion on comparing two arguments or using an arithmetic expression.